# Getting file system errors consistently on a Samsung PM951 NVMe drive

Tags: linux, filesystems, hardware

I have been using this laptop for almost a year with no problems dual-booting KDE neon(Ubuntu-based distro) and Windows 10, and recently I started getting file system errors and a system freeze afterwards (cannot login in virtual terminals but can do REISUB).
The system freezes or starts misbehaving and then I switch to the virtual terminal and I see the errors (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gugSt.jpg)
Fscking fixes the errors but they come again later, and even a bad cluster check doesn't show any problems, I tried formatting the partition and re-installing neon but they came back shortly (in less than a day).

Windows seems to work properly but unfortunately there are no tools from Samsung to help diagnose problems for this drive or report device health.

Where can I dig further and what tools can help me analyze this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a known bug with recent kernels and Samsung SSDs, solution is:

> Until a proper fix is implemented, a workaround is suggested, which
>   involves **adding a kernel parameter**:
>
> > Please try nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500, if the issue
> >     persists, please try nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200.

Full solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/906105